# Unable to put newline in Output text area in Coach BPM 8.5.7

Tags: user-interface, textarea, newline, bpmn

I have a variable binded with output text area in which i am trying to put new line by putting in \n in the implementation of the variable but it doesnt put the newline in the output text area also, it doesnt show the \n in the text in the output text area.

Anyone has a work around for it?

Answer (score 1):

works using html breakline

```
<br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the the coach view "Display text", which has replaced "Output Text" in IBM BAW, you must also check the option "Allow HTML" under Configuration->Behavior. Otherwise the 
 tag will be escaped.